# Undefined array in Vuex payload using firestore where ' in ' query

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuexfire

I am trying to make an 'in' query like this: db.collection('units').where('SuperID', 'in', payload)

SuperID: is a number

payload: is an array of numbers matching the SuperIDs

I am doing this so I can group users based off a document like this

[image]

**Vuex Store**

```
getgs: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef, payload }) => {
      //return the promise returned by 'bindFirestoreRef'
      return bindFirestoreRef('gs', db.collection('units').where('SuperID', 'in', payload))
    }),
```

**Method**

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getgs']),

  ggs(payload){

      console.log(payload)

      this.getgs(payload)
  }
}
```

[image: It console logs payload but then says its undefined]

Whenever I try to call it, it logs the array that I need but then says that its undefined and throws the Firebase error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I found the answer this time.

Using this example from the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html):

```
actions: {
  checkout ({ commit, state }, products) {
    // save the items currently in the cart
    const savedCartItems = [...state.cart.added]
    // send out checkout request, and optimistically
    // clear the cart
    commit(types.CHECKOUT_REQUEST)
    // the shop API accepts a success callback and a failure callback
    shop.buyProducts(
      products,
      // handle success
      () => commit(types.CHECKOUT_SUCCESS),
      // handle failure
      () => commit(types.CHECKOUT_FAILURE, savedCartItems)
    )
  }
}
```

It looks like your action definition should be

```
getgs: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }, payload) => {
      //return the promise returned by 'bindFirestoreRef'
      return bindFirestoreRef('gs', db.collection('units').where('SuperID', 'in', payload))
    }),
```

With the payload outside of the context object.

Comment: Sadly it did not work. I was hoping it was something small like this that I overlooked.

Comment: Thanks.. so weird because I use 


firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef, state }) => {

 with 0 problems

Comment: Cool, glad I could help!